# Python script for replacing values doesn't run at all

Tags: python, replace, dataset, spyder, nan

I have a problem with running my script - even though it's really short and seems simple. I wanted to replace all the 0 in my table with NaN and ran this:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\prices.csv')

dataset.loc[2]=dataset.loc[2].replace(0, 'NaN')

csv_data = dataset.to_csv(None, header = False, index = False)
    
output_file = 'C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\dataset_clear.txt'
   
with open(output_file,'w') as output:
       output.write(csv_data[:-1])
```

My Spyder (python 2.7) runs all other scripts but when it comes to this one it starts running it and after a few minutes the whole spyder stops working and I have to close it and open again, does anyone know what might cause it? Is it something wrong with the script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the NAs in the 2nd column(index will be 1), try this -

```
import numpy as np
dataset.iloc[:,1]=dataset.iloc[:,1].replace(0, np.NaN)
```

But if you want to replace all the NAs in the entire dataset, try this -

```
dataset = dataset.replace(0,np.NaN) #spelling corrected
```

Note that dataframe.iloc() is integer-location based indexing for selection by position while dataframe.loc() is label based access